# ExifInterface Tag exposure time cannot be resolved in eclipse

Tags: android

I am using API level 8 , documentation says its available after API level 5 !
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html#TAG_EXPOSURE_TIME

I am trying to use like this ,

```
exifObj.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_EXPOSURE_TIME)
```

but not able to resolve the ExifInterface.TAG_EXPOSURE_TIME in eclipse !

I get make , model etc. but few tags like exposure time and aperture I am not able to use !?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have misread the documentation.

`TAG_EXPOSURE_TIME` is available since API level 11.

Comment: Ah.. right , So EXIFInterface is available from API 5 , and TAG_EXPOSURE_TIME from API level 11( bad that its on right corner, and is not highlighted) ! Thanks.

Comment: @mgv: I get the same error with TAG_FOCAL_LENGTH, that was introduced in API 8 (I'm using API 10). Clues??